# Strange "Network 93" appears as an active network with internet access

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am using a Windows 11 PC, and I recently had something very strange happen with my home Wifi network. When I connected to my home Wifi network, in addition to the name of my home network appearing as an active connection, I also noticed that a strange "Network 93" appeared as an active connection with internet access.

Incidentally, at the same time, I was composing a question to post on Stack Overflow. When I attempted to post the question, I received this error:

```
Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience.
```

In response, I immediately turned off Wifi and made my device private. When I connected to the internet again, I no longer saw this "Network 93" and Stack Overflow allowed me to post the question.

I'm not sure what the explanation for this is, but it's as if some strange Wifi sharing was going on. Could this possibly be hacking? Should I be worried?

Comment: Do a full offline scan with Windows Defender and let it quarantine viruses

Comment: Since your work on the PC indicates the issues is there, another possibility, IoT devices being hacked to serve as spambots or in DDOS attacks is less likely. In particular, look at any browser add-ons. Try GlassWire, https://www.glasswire.com/ , to see what is using that connection.